# Angular Material 2 md-checkbox default doesn't work with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a reactive form that uses a md-checkbox with a default value of false, however when I submit the form without toggling the checkbox the value returned in the form data is null.

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(someForm)">
  <md-checkbox formControlName="allowDependents"></md-checkbox>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
export class SomeComponent {
  private allowDependents: FormControl = new FormControl(false);
  private someForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.someForm = formBuilder.group({
      'allowDependents': this.allowDependents
    });
  }

  private onSubmit(formData: any): void {
    //  formData.value.allowDependents === null if the checkbox has not been toggled but it should be false.
  }
}
```

Also if I set the default value for the form control to true, still the checkbox is not checked by default, the value is null.

I also tried updating the template to this. `<md-checkbox formControlName="allowDependents" [checked]="true">` and still the checkbox was not checked, I further removed the formControlName attribute but left checked equals true and now finally the checkbox is checked. Based on that behavior it would seem the value is being overridden by the form group but is being set to null instead of true/false.

Comment: It should work https://plnkr.co/edit/ea9r3VpBEnWzxng0M5Ro?p=preview

Comment: The newest version of Angular Material may have an [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1018) with value accessor for various input elements